# Java ProcessBuilder executing command has no output

Tags: java, command-line, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to execute git command inside my java application. The output string is correct when the command is "git status" or "git branch", however the output was empty when the command is "git clone". I wonder how can I get the output string of "git clone". Thanks in advance.

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("git", "clone", "address");
    Process pr = pb.start();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String cmdLine = "";
    while ((cmdLine = buf.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(cmdLine);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: Jut to be sure: when you run the same with "git status"; it works? And you are sure that when you run "git clone **real-address** it works? And that "address" is a **real-address** when you run the java code?

Comment: The output is likely being written to stderr instead of stdout.  Try adding 

    `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);`

before starting the process.

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah it works."Git status" shows everything i need and the files are downloaded by "git clone" except the outputs..

Comment: @JimGarrison Yeah, the stderr has the output, but it only contains the first line "Cloning into 'my_project'". Are there any ways to read the outputs completely? Thank you so much.